# Limit number of rows returned ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I want to limit the number of rows returned when using a statement with an ORDER BY clause.

One of my columns has an ID not unique to the row and so appears multiple times. If I use a LIMIT at the end of the statement it would limit the results entirely, not at the SELECT point. The LIMIT might be 3, in which case three rows for each ID would be returned.

```
id  |  .........

1   |  .........
1   |  ........
1   |  .......
1   |  ......
1   |  .....
2   |  ....
2   |  ...
2   |  ..
2   |  .
```

The end of my statement has:

```
ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from table t
where (select count(*)
       from table t2
       where t2.id = t.id and t2.date >= t.date
      ) <= 3
order by id, date desc;
```

This counts the number of dates for an id that are equal to or larger than the date in a row, and only keeps the rows where the count is less than or equal to 3.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation would make sense, but I'm unsure what 'table t2' is.

Comment: @ButtressCoral . . . `table` is meant to be the name of your table.  The `t2` is a table alias, a basic part of the SQL language.